# message "Invalid column name." when using check()

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I got this message "Invalid column name 'status'" when using check() to denote categorical variables from the code below. Can anyone resolve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[trips]
(
    id int,
    client_id int,
    driver_id int,
    city_id int,
    status varchar(128) check(status in('completed', 'cancelled_by_driver', 'cancelled_by_client')),
    request_at date
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[trips] (id, client_id, driver_id, city_id, status, request_at)
SELECT '1', '1', '10', '1',  'completed', '2013-10-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '2', '11', '1',  'cancelled_by_driver', '2013-10-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '3', '12', '6',  'completed', '2013-10-01'
```

---Edit---
Sorry for my original example with inconsistent levels of the "status" column: The line, "status varchar(128) check(status in('small', 'medium', 'large'))" has to be replaced by  "status varchar(128) check(status in('completed', 'cancelled_by_driver', 'cancelled_by_client'))."

Besides, after deleting existing tables with the same name, "trips," I can create the table now. The table duplication causes the problem.

Comment: I ran your script and don't get an invalid column name error. Instead. I get the expected check constraint violation error because 'completed' is not valid.

Comment: Unable to re-create. I got the same result as @DanGuzman for the same reason.

Comment: Since Status is a reserved word try wrapping it in square brackets.

Comment: No it isn't, @MarkKram : [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It seems a `dbo.tripa` table already exists in the database but without the `status` column. You get the error because `INSERT` statement is compiled using that table instead of the one you are trying to create. Of course, the `CREATE` will also fail because the table already exists.

Comment: The batch *should* abort if the `CREATE` fails though, @DanGuzman , so the `INSERT` wouldn't happen. Unless the `INSERT` is in a different batch and the OP doesn't display that in their question (which I wouldn't be surprised by).

Comment: @Larnu, agreed the batch will abort if the create fails. In this case though, the batch containing both the create table and insert will never even execute because of the compilation error.

Comment: Good point, @DanGuzman, hadn't considered that. As always, why it's so important to OP provides code that replicates the problem I suppose. All of this is just based on "educated" guesses. ;)

Comment: @Dan Guzman, Larnu You are right. Please see my edit. After deleting an existing file with the same name and substituting the "status..." line with a correct one, I can create the table I want.

Comment: @MarkKram "status" is not a reserved term in SQL Server v18.2, which I am using now.